# Custom controller configuration changes all controllers setting

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, custom-attributes, asp.net-apicontroller

I am developing an application which uses webapi controllers. I just need to set some setting for a ***Specific*** controller not ***ALL***! I use IControllerConfiguration and in the initialize method set ***type name handling*** setting. I expect that this setting just applied to only one contoller with the attribute but it applies to All, ALL other controllers also use this new setting wrongly! I need to apply custom attribute ***ONLY*** on the Schedulecontoller   is there any solution please thanks.

```
 public class CustomJson245Attribute : Attribute, IControllerConfiguration
    {
        public void Initialize(HttpControllerSettings controllerSettings, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
        {
            controllerSettings.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling= TypeNameHandling.Auto;
           // formatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
        }
    }

[CustomJson245]
public class ScheduleController : ApiController
{}
```

I do not need this controller's setting to change! but it changes as ScheduleSetting.

```
  public class SimpleController : ApiController
    {}
```

EDITED
I finally found the answer,

```
 public void Initialize(HttpControllerSettings controllerSettings, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
            {
    controllerSettings.Formatters.Clear();
                controllerSettings.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() { SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto} });
}
```

Comment: Override the constructor in the subclass.

Comment: how to do  that?, please I am some how new in webapi , thank you very much. what should I do in the overrided constructor?

Comment: This is not related to webapi, just need C# knowledge, which can be searched on the web relatively easily.

Comment: thanks a lot my friend , but i didnt get my answer. I can override the constructor but what should I do to specify the setting just to the contoller, not to ALL contollers. this is my question! but again thanks for the response

Comment: Show your effort? Also show the code of one more controller which you don't want to change the setting.

Comment: You should answer your own question with your edit above. I spent way too long trying to debug my controllers, turned out to be the same issue.